# Apply a pairwise function on the columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r

I would like to apply some pairwise correlation estimator on all the columns of large matrix. Since I am working with large dimensions, I am looking for a function that might be of help here. I have been experimenting with the `apply` function but I have not gotten very far so all help is greatly appreciated.

```
require(ccaPP)
require(mvtnorm)
d<- 10
Sigma <- matrix(0.2, nrow = d, ncol = d)
diag(Sigma) <- 1
#Data generation
X <- rmvnorm(100, sigma = Sigma) # 100 x d matrix
Q <- apply(X, 2, FUN = corQuadrant, consistent = TRUE)
```

I apologise if this has been asked before but a search did not reveal something I can use. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelChirico You have them, this is what the function `rmvnorm` does. It generates data from a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Well, if you apply the `cor` function, a symmetric matrix is returned with ones in the diagonal. Something similar hopefully but I can deal with it even if it's a list or something like that. The important thing is to consider all pairs.

Comment: I think you already answered this yourself @JohnK. cor() does exactly what you are looking for. If you really want you can remove the lower half and diagonal of the correlation matrix afterwards, and optionally convert it to a sparse Matrix to conserve memory if this is necessary.

Comment: @dww No, `cor` is not appropriate here because the function that I am using, `corQuadrant` does something entirely different. And it's pairwise only. That's why I am looking to extend it to matrices. Any suggestions about that?

Comment: A bit slower than apply, but nested for loops should get you where you need to go. Something like:  for (i in 1: (NCOL(X) -1) { for (j in ((i+1):NCOL(X)) {answer[i,j] <- corQuadrant( X[,i], X[,j] ) }

Comment: @dww Thanks. If you would like to to upgrade your comment to a full answer, I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested for loops are one way:

```
require(ccaPP)
require(mvtnorm)
d<- 10
Sigma <- matrix(0.2, nrow = d, ncol = d)
diag(Sigma) <- 1
#Data generation
X <- rmvnorm(100, sigma = Sigma) # 100 x d matrix
Q <- matrix(nrow = d,ncol = d)
for (i in 1: (d-1)) { 
  for (j in (i+1):d) {
    Q[i,j] <- corQuadrant( X[,i], X[,j] ) 
  }
}
```